# Entity Framework 6 and SQLite / Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to use Entity Framework 6 Code First with SQLite databases.

The problem is that the database is never initialized with the schema (no tables created). I'm guessing it's because I'm passing a SQLiteConnection to the subclassed DBContext, and because the database always exists (although file size=0), the Initializer never runs.

The data I want to work with:

```
class Game
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
}

class GameContext : DbContext
{
    public GameContext(String filename)
        : base( new SQLiteConnection() { ConnectionString = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder() { DataSource = filename, ForeignKeys = true,  }.ConnectionString }, true)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
}
```

Opening the database and creating a sample object:

```
using (var db = new GameContext("prueba7.sqlite"))
{
    Game g = new Game { Title = "Juego 1" };

    db.Games.Add(g);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The innter exception error is: {"SQL logic error or missing database\r\nno such table: Game"}

If I enable logging (Database.Log=Console.Write;) I see some queries and errors after opening the DB:

> SQLite error (1): no such table: __MigrationHistory
>
> SQLite error (1): no such table: EdmMetadata
>
> -- Failed in 32 ms with error: SQL logic error or missing database
>   no such table: Game

I tried creating a custom Initializator like the following, but as I said, that code never runs... the Database.Exists() always returns true.

```
public class Initializer : IDatabaseInitializer<GameContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(GameContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            context.Database.Create();
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: the sqlite provider will create the database as soon as the context is opened. and the regular sqlite provider does not support creating tables, so a regular code first approach (with the provider I'm aware of) is not possible.